# Passport-facebook-token keeps returning 401

Tags: ios, node.js, facebook, passport.js, passport-facebook

Currently, I am using NodeJS with Express and Passport-facebook-token module for my iOS app. I am having trouble with this because the service is always returning 401 response even though we are getting passed the OAuth logic. Any ideas with this code as to why it keeps returning 401 even though it successfully authenticated and came to our `handleAuthentiation` method but doesn't reach the method I have `console.log("THIS IS NOT BEING CALLED")` called out in?

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var database = require('./database.js');
var passport = require('passport'),
    FacebookTokenStrategy = require('passport-facebook-token').Strategy;

var User = require('./User.js');
var app = express();

//setup json parsing
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//setup facebook authentication
passport.use(new FacebookTokenStrategy({
        clientID: "2454efafd33r",
        clientSecret: "323245343"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        User.handleAuthentication(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done, function(err, user) {
            console.log("handleAuthentication user is " + JSON.stringify(user));
            console.log("handleAuthentication error is " + JSON.stringify(err));
            done(err, user);
        });
    }
));

app.post('/auth/facebook/token',
    passport.authenticate('facebook-token'),
    function(req, res) {

        console.log("THIS IS NOT BEING CALLED");

        // do something with req.user
        res.status(200);
        res.send(user);
    }
);

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

I am trying to trace the call thorough the other libraries and I cant seem to find any method that has `success` defined. I noticed that `done` method is mapped to verified which then calls `success`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out. Turns out i was not initializing Oauth correctly. I needed to set the following:

```
// Configure Express
app.use(logger('combined'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));
app.use(session({secret: 'supernova', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: Im getting the same issue but im using the sails.js framework, which of these configs did the magic ?

Answer (score 0):

For me I used the example in the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-facebook-token, so **i didn't add '.Strategy'**

and for method "POST" as in the question, **I sent, as body, from the front-end:**

```
const tokenBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({access_token: response.accessToken}, null, 2)], {type : 'application/json'});
```

as explained in: https://medium.com/@alexanderleon/implement-social-authentication-with-react-restful-api-9b44f4714fa

Good luck!